# Integer and protection against injection

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-injection

Im using nodejs. When creating a vanilla sql query I have this:

```
var id = req.body.id;
var query = "select from table where id = " + id;
```

Now, what I knew is that you should escape integer this way:

```
var id = parseInt(req.body.id);
```

Is that correct? Or you should escape like a string? Or not escape at all?

Comment: "escape" is probably not the right term in this case. `parseInt` checks whether or not the string starts with a base 10 (by default) integer and leaves the rest of the string behind. This is a good protection in my opinion.

Comment: You mean parseInt is a good protection?

Comment: Yes I think so, since only base 10 integers are accepted, anything else will give `NaN` (Not A Number).

Comment: @procrastinator: No, `parseInt` isn't "good protection." Using property paramterized queries is good protection.

Comment: I agree @T.J.Crowder, I mean for this specific case I think it's enough.

Answer (score 3):

> Is that correct?

No, not remotely.

> Or you should escape like a string?

No. Nor should *you* escape strings.

> Or not escape at all?

For numbers *and* strings (and other), use whatever the parameterized version of the database API you're using is ("prepared statements" or similar), don't "escape" things.

For instance, suppose you were using the [`mysql` npm module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql). Per [the documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries), that query would be:

```
connection.query('select from table where id = ?', [req.body.id], function (error, results, fields) {
  // ...
});
```

That leaves the "escaping" to the module providing the API. If you're using a reputable one, it's been thoroughly tested and battle-proven, as opposed to any ad hoc solutions.

More: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use a sanitizer to purge your inputs from SQL Injections.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitizer